# hey guys how to use spring boot session with angular project

Tags: angular, spring-boot, session

how to use spring boot session with angular project
i want to send the login and password with that requet POST in the second picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv6UO.png)

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: how to integrate spring security and spring session with my angular project

Answer (score -1):

angular  is a frontend framework. After build you get static html, css and js. You can put this on every server (nginx, tomcat, whatever).  See [Communicating with backend services using HTTP](https://angular.io/guide/http)

You can 'connect' you angular via ajax calls with spring boot. But you have to set CORS in your spring boot backend. See: [spring boot and cors](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

This is a good article how to use jwt in angular and spring boot: [angular-spring-boot-jwt-auth](https://bezkoder.com/angular-spring-boot-jwt-auth/)

Comment: ive tried that article but in the end it says that the role is not found and i have im my data base roles like he use them in the spring app